# Rails: destroy_all and update has_many size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following relationship:

```
class Match
  has_many :players
end
```

In one example case, I have a match with 2 players, one with the attribute team = 1 and the other team = 2

After I call `match.players.where(team: 1).destroy_all`, there is code that gets executed below that uses `match.players.size`
However, instead of the size being 2, the size now is 3. How can I update the size attribute? I can't call `match.reload` because there were other changes made to this object during this execution

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using `counter_cache` for this, so your player model gets:

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :match, dependent: :destroy, counter_cache: true
end
```

You'll have to generate a migration and:

```
add_column :matches, :player_count, :integer
```

That way when a player is added/removed from the match the counter cache column will automatically be updated.

More info here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache